# R shiny C3 scatterD3 conflicting

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, c3.js, htmlwidgets

The following minimal reproducible example works fine, but when I uncomment `scatterD3Output("scatterPlot", height = "700px")` it stops working: **no error is given, but no output is shown**.

Are the C3 and scatterD3 libraries incompatible?

**UPDATE:**
The problem seems to be that `C3` is based on d3v3 and `scatterD3` on d3v4

```
library(shiny)
library(C3)
library(scatterD3)

server = function(input, output) {
  my_df = reactive({
    input$button
    my_df = list(a=runif(1,0,100),b=runif(1,0,100),c=runif(1,0,100))
    list(my_df=my_df)
  })
  output$my_pie = renderC3Pie({
    C3Pie(value = my_df()$my_df)
  })
  output$scatterPlot <- renderScatterD3({
    scatterD3(x=1,y=1)
  })
}

ui = shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
      actionButton('button', "Draw!"),
      C3PieOutput('my_pie')
    ),
    fluidRow(
      br()#,scatterD3Output("scatterPlot", height = "700px")
    )
  )
)
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: they are conflicting, right click and inspect the element then console gives errors

Comment: thanks, the error is `TypeError: c.scale is undefined`. Do you know what it means and how to fix it? I'm not familiar with javascript.